# Javascript: Using regEx to change more than one character or group of characters at a time

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, textarea, getelementbyid

I know how to code fairly simple regular expressions, my question is about changing more than one character or characters at a time - Not more than one instance of a character or characters, but more than one match characters or characters to separate values in one call to replace.

For instance, if I want to change all newline characters to <br> in text from a textarea, I might code:

```
var withoutNewLines = document.getElementById("taInput").value.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
```

If I want to change all spaces to &nbsp;, I'd code:

```
var withoutNewLines = document.getElementById("taInput").value.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;");
```

If I want to change both in one statement, I'd code:

```
var withoutNewLines = document.getElementById("taInput").value.replace(/\n/g, "<br>").replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;");
```

My question is:

Is there a way to code one regular expression which could be used to make both changes with only one call to replace()?

Comment: Look at the MDN docs for RegExp and the replace method, and youll see that you can use "|" in the regex to act as "or", and you can pass a function as the second parameter to the replace call

Comment: For a global replace, Ian's solution works but I would probably just run two separate replace calls like you have in your question.

Comment: @OldPro I agree, I just wanted to provide what I thought they were looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unnecessary, but you could try:

```
var newStr = "Some string".replace(/o|m/g, function (match) {
    if (match === "o") {
        return "i";
    } else if (match === "m") {
        return "r";
    }
});
console.log(newStr);
```

Where this is replacing all "o" with "i", and all "m" with "r".

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @OldPro Thanks for the reply. I think I'll stick with multiple replace calls. I would be posting this for notification to Ian also but this bloody software only allows notifying one user in comments. I'll comment "to" Ian separately.

Comment: @OldPro Thanks for the reply. As you suggested, I think I'll stick with multiple replace calls. I doubt it takes more CPU time than using a combined replace with the OR character. I would be posting this for notification to Ian also but this bloody software only allows notifying one user in comments.